# Remove selected/highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text in div `selectable` and I want to allow the user to remove text by selecting the text using their cursor.

It works fine, but if you click on the text, everything is removed. If you click and drag to select, it works fine.

What can I do to make it work with my text properly. If user clicks the text, it shouldn't remove everything.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkbmawq/) for testing.

jQuery:

```
    if (window.getSelection().toString() != "") {
        selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
        var text1 = $(".selectable").text().split("")
        pointStart = window.getSelection().anchorOffset
        pointEnd = window.getSelection().focusOffset

        if (pointEnd < pointStart) {
            pointStart = pointEnd
        }
        text1.splice(pointStart, selectedText.length);
        text1 = text1.join("")
    } else {
        selectedText = $(".selectable").text()
        var text1 = ""
    }
$(".selectable").text(text1)
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="selectable">
   Hello world what is 進撃の巨人 reality test test... test.
</div>
```

EDIT: Potential solution:

```
if (window.getSelection().toString() == "") {
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your else statement is causing that behavior. When no text is selected it grabs all the text then sets text1 to a blank string. Then your last line of code sets the text in the div to text1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error lies on the `else` part. If the user has not selected any text, which is the case of simply clicking on the text, your `else` code block gets executed.

In that block you assign `var text1 = "";`

Later you assing `text1` as the text content of your `$(".selectable")` element.

Just change that line to:

```
var text1 = selectedText;
```

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkbmawq/5/)

I also suggest you declare `var text1` only once at the top of your mouseup handler and change your assignments from `var text1 = "value"` to `text1 = "value"`

See: [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: Or just get rid of the else statement and move the last line inside the first if statement. The else statement isn't really needed.

Comment: Can you please edit the jsFiddle with your solution https://jsfiddle.net/5Lkbmawq/  particularly the part where I should move hte variable to the top as I'm not sure what you mean. Thanks.